# How do I manually add additional rows to the bottom of an ASP.NET gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a situation where I'm populating a gridview with a bound data source, and want two additional rows at the very bottom; one to show the sum of values in the columns and one to show the average of values in the columns.  I can quite easily calculate these values by aggregating information taken from the rowDataBound event, but don't know how to go about manually adding the additional two rows to the gridview.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Footer just like you use Headers in gridview. Another solution is use a query in such way:

query 1 : your original query

```
UNION
```

query 2 : your query which contains sum

(This applies only if you don't apply paging to your grid)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single row of information you can use summary footer. See [Displaying Summary Information in the GridView's Footer](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-15-cs.aspx).

[image]
<sub>(source: [asp.net](http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/15fig01css.png))</sub>

If you want two additional rows, you can stuff rows into an [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx). At the business logic layer, you can add more rows to the list returned by DAL.

Comment: Yeah, i think i'll have to go with the idea to stuff the additional two rows into the IList.  Not ideal, but it'll suffice.  Thanks.